# Must declare the scalar variable "@tempattend" in sql procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error stating that I Must declare the table variable "@tempattend".
Please help me. How can I pass `@tempattend` table to `@tempTableSelect` variable?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rl_LM_AHS]

 @SupEmpID nvarchar(10),
 @SectorName nvarchar(300),
 @dateList nvarchar(300),
 @Month nvarchar(5),
 @Year nvarchar(5),
 @SearchType nvarchar(10)


AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @tempTableSelect nvarchar(2000)
    DECLARE @tempattend Table
(
    [Emp.ID] nvarchar(10),
    [Name] nvarchar(60),
    [1] nvarchar(3) null,
    [2] nvarchar(3) null,
    [3] nvarchar(3) null
    upto ..............
    [31] nvarchar(3) null
)

IF (@SearchType = 1)
    BEGIN

--INSERT TEAM LIST TO @tempattend TABLE
 insert into @tempattend([Emp.ID],[Name]) (Select EMP.empID as [Emp.ID],CONCAT(EMP.emp_fname,' ',COALESCE(nullif(EMP.emp_Mname,'') +' ',''),COALESCE(nullif(EMP.emp_Lname,'') +' ','')) as [Name] from EShiftHistory)

set @tempTableSelect = 'select [Emp.ID],Name,' + @dateList +' from @tempattend'

    EXEC (@tempTableSelect)

    END


END
```

Comment: Please work in you acceptance ratio. If you don't take the time to accept answers the stackoverflow community will not benefit as it should.

Answer (score 5):

You should write

```
set @tempTableSelect = 'select [Emp.ID],Name,' + @dateList +' from @tempattend'
```

`@tempattend` is a temporary table variable. It holds a table, not some value like `@datelist`.

But why do you `EXEC` instead of just selecting directly from the table?

---

Come to think of it: It may not be possible to use memory temp tables in `EXEC` statements. Try turning this

```
DECLARE @tempattend Table
```

into

```
CREATE TABLE #tempattend
```

and change every occurance of `@tempattend` to `#tempattend`.

Comment: Exec is needed because of the datelist, which can be several columns. You can't select from a tabel variable since it is in a different scope. So as far as i can tell, your answer is wrong

Comment: getting error after changes, Must declare the table variable "@tempattend".

Comment: See my edit, please. You can't use an in-memory temp table variables here. You need to create a "real" temp table.

Comment: so what is the difference between these two temp tables.Kindly explain

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Thorsten Dittmar's answer, why not something like this?

```
select empID,
 CONCAT(emp_fname,' ',
 COALESCE(emp_Mname,''),
 COALESCE(nullif(emp_Lname,''))) as [Name]
    from EShiftHistory
```

I realize you're trying to do some dynamic selection with the `@dateList` variable, but that's a strong signal that you should either normalize your tables *or* just let your client code pick out which columns it wants. (Not everything needs to be done in raw SQL.)

Numbers as column names? Definitely problematic.

Comment: Thank you all for reply, it's working after changed to CREATE TABLE #tempattend

Comment: Excellent. Please click on the "acceptance" indicator for the best answer.